# History process instance query filter on boolean variable

Tags: rest, camunda

ENV: camunda 7.4 with tomcat8, jdk1.8.0_40 and h2 in-memory database.
API: REST -> /history/process-instance (GET)

Filter on boolean variable like below

```
oneFlag_eq_false
```

does not work. The API document for that endpoint says the value will be treated as String on server side. Anyone knows how to apply this on a boolean variable?

```
oneFlag_eq_0
```

does not work either.

```
oneFlag_neq_1 or oneFlag_neq_true
```

doesn't do the filter at all.

Comment: camunda has a cryptic implementation down that road, at least for now. Solution now is to provide customized endpoint and implement it using the HistoricService directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [POST /history/process-instance](https://docs.camunda.org/manual/latest/reference/rest/history/process-instance/post-process-instance-query/) query allows to query with boolean values.

Example reqeuest body:

```
{
  "variables": [
    {
      "name": "oneFlag",
      "operator": "eq",
      "value": false
    }]
 }
```